# The method to use gradient accumulate in BERT finetune

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, gradient, accumulate

I was doing a Bert finetune and I had OOM issues. I heard a good method to handle this is to use "gradient accumulate". Below are my optimization.py(include the gradient accumulate)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import re
import tensorflow as tf



from tensorflow.python.training import optimizer
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops





def create_optimizer(loss, init_lr, num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, use_tpu):
  """Creates an optimizer training op."""
  global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()

  learning_rate = tf.constant(value=init_lr, shape=[], dtype=tf.float32)

  # Implements linear decay of the learning rate.
  learning_rate = tf.train.polynomial_decay(
      learning_rate,
      global_step,
      num_train_steps,
      end_learning_rate=0.0,
      power=1.0,
      cycle=False)

  # Implements linear warmup. I.e., if global_step < num_warmup_steps, the
  # learning rate will be `global_step/num_warmup_steps * init_lr`.
  if num_warmup_steps:
    global_steps_int = tf.cast(global_step, tf.int32)
    warmup_steps_int = tf.constant(num_warmup_steps, dtype=tf.int32)

    global_steps_float = tf.cast(global_steps_int, tf.float32)
    warmup_steps_float = tf.cast(warmup_steps_int, tf.float32)

    warmup_percent_done = global_steps_float / warmup_steps_float
    warmup_learning_rate = init_lr * warmup_percent_done

    is_warmup = tf.cast(global_steps_int < warmup_steps_int, tf.float32)
    learning_rate = (
        (1.0 - is_warmup) * learning_rate + is_warmup * warmup_learning_rate)

  # It is recommended that you use this optimizer for fine tuning, since this
  # is how the model was trained (note that the Adam m/v variables are NOT
  # loaded from init_checkpoint.)
  optimizer = MultistepAdamWeightDecayOptimizer(
      learning_rate=learning_rate,
      weight_decay_rate=0.01,
      beta_1=0.9,
      beta_2=0.999, # 0.98 ONLY USED FOR PRETRAIN. MUST CHANGE AT FINE-TUNING 0.999,
      epsilon=1e-6,
      exclude_from_weight_decay=["LayerNorm", "layer_norm", "bias"])

  if use_tpu:
    optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(optimizer)

  tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
  grads = tf.gradients(loss, tvars)

  # This is how the model was pre-trained.
  (grads, _) = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads, clip_norm=1.0)

  train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(
      zip(grads, tvars), global_step=global_step)

  # Normally the global step update is done inside of `apply_gradients`.
  # However, `AdamWeightDecayOptimizer` doesn't do this. But if you use
  # a different optimizer, you should probably take this line out.
  new_global_step = global_step + 1
  train_op = tf.group(train_op, [global_step.assign(new_global_step)])
  return train_op


class MultistepAdamWeightDecayOptimizer(optimizer.Optimizer):
  """A basic Adam optimizer that includes "correct" L2 weight decay."""

  def __init__(self,
               learning_rate,
               weight_decay_rate=0.0,
               beta_1=0.9,
               beta_2=0.999,
               n = 1,
               epsilon=1e-6,
               exclude_from_weight_decay=None,
               name="MultistepAdamWeightDecayOptimizer"):
    """Constructs a AdamWeightDecayOptimizer."""
    super(MultistepAdamWeightDecayOptimizer, self).__init__(False, name)

    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.weight_decay_rate = weight_decay_rate
    self.beta_1 = beta_1
    self.beta_2 = beta_2
    self.epsilon = epsilon
    self._n = n

    self.exclude_from_weight_decay = exclude_from_weight_decay

    self._n_t = None


  def _prepare(self):
    super(MultistepAdamWeightDecayOptimizer, self)._prepare()
    self._n_t=tf.convert_to_tensor(self._n, name="n")

  def _create_slots(self,var_list):

    super(MultistepAdamWeightDecayOptimizer, self)._create_slots(var_list)
    first_var = min(var_list, key=lambda x: x.name)
    self._create_non_slot_variable(initial_value=0 if self._n == 1 else 1,
                                   name="iter",
                                   colocate_with=first_var)

    for v in var_list:
      self._zeros_slot(v,"grad_acc",self._name)

  def _get_iter_variable(self):
    if tf.contrib.eager.in_eager_mode():
      graph = None
    else:
      graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    return self._get_non_slot_variable("iter", graph=graph)


  def apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, global_step=None, name=None):
    """See base class."""
    update_ops = []

    var_list = [v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None]


    with ops.init_scope():
      self._create_slots(var_list)
    self._prepare()



    for(grad, param) in grads_and_vars:
      if grad is None or param is None:
        continue

      grad_acc = self.get_slot(param, "grad_acc")
      param_name = self._get_variable_name(params.name)


      m = tf.get_variable(name=param_name + "/adam_m", shape=param.shape.as_list(),
          dtype=tf.float32,trainable=False, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

      v = tf.get_variable(name =param_name + "/adam_v", shape=param.sahpe.as_list(),
          dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())




      def _apply_adam(grad_acc, grad, param, m, v):
        total_grad = (grad_acc + grad) / tf.cast(self._n_t, grad.dtype)



        next_m = (
          tf.multiply(self.beta_1, m) + tf.multiply(1.0 - self.beta_1, total_grad))
        next_v = (
          tf.multiply(self.beta_2, v) + tf.multiply(1.0 - self.beta_2,
                                                    tf.square(total_grad)))

        update = next_m / (tf.sqrt(next_v) + self.epsilon)
        if self._do_use_weight_decay(param_name):
          update += self.weight_decay_rate * param
        update_with_lr =self.learning_rate * update
        next_param = param - update_with_lr
        adam_op = tf.group(param.assign(next_param), m.assign(next_m),
                       v.assign(next_v))
        with tf.control_dependencies([adam_op]):
           grad_acc_to_zero_op = grad_acc.assign(tf.zero_like(grad_acc), use_locking=self._use_locking)
        return tf.group(adam_op, grad_acc_to_zero_op)

      def _accumulate_gradient(grad_acc, grad):
         assign_up = tf.assign_add(grad_acc, grad, use_locking=self._use_locking)
         return tf.group(assign_op)

      update_op = tf.cond(tf.equal(self._get_iter_variable(),0),
                     lambda: _apply_adam(grad_acc, grad, param,m, v),
                     lambda: _accumulate_gradient(grad_acc, grad))
      update_ops.append(update_op)

    apply_updates = self._finish(update_ops, name_scope=name)
    return apply_updates

  def _finish(self, update_ops, name_scope):
    iter_=self._get_iter_variable()
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
      with tf.colocate_with(iter_):
        update_iter = iter_.assign(tf.mod(iter_+1, self._n_t),
                                      use_locking=self._use_locking)

    return tf.group(
           *update_ops + [update_iter], name=name_scope)

  def _do_use_weight_decay(self, param_name):
    """Whether to use L2 weight decay for `param_name`."""
    if not self.weight_decay_rate:
      return False
    if self.exclude_from_weight_decay:
      for r in self.exclude_from_weight_decay:
        if re.search(r, param_name) is not None:
          return False
    return True

  def _get_variable_name(self, param_name):
    """Get the variable name from the tensor name."""
    m = re.match("^(.*):\\d+$", param_name)
    if m is not None:
      param_name = m.group(1)
    return param_name
```

After I used this optimization.py, i could use large batch. But loss did not decrease and after  300 steps(i got 550000 training data, batch size 64, iteration 1000 and epoch 20), it said: train loop marked as finished and stopped. 
I am not sure what problem is, could you please help me out? thanks.

Comment: Could you more specific. If you can boil down your question to one simple(r) reproducible problem that others can work on that would be easier to help on. Please edit and simplify your question.

Comment: Thanks, oaxacamatt, I modified the question

Comment: Can you provide the part of the code for your created model and the model.fit part? How did you use the optimization.py?